# Forge server 1.17.1 on Linux won't run - No main manifest attribute

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to get a Minecraft forge server up and running.  I have Java 16:

```
[opc@better-minecraft1 ~]$ java --version
java 16.0.2 2021-07-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode)
```

Vanilla Minecraft server 1.17.1 is installed (also in `/home/opc/`) and working fine.

I downloaded the Forge installer from https://files.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.17.1.html.  Then I ran the installer with `java -jar forge-1.17.1-37.1.0-installer.jar --installServer` (still in the same directory).  This seemed to work - the last line of the output was `The server installed successfully`.

Now I have two problems.  First, I was expecting the Forge jar to appear in the directory but it didn't.  I eventually found it in `/home/opc/libraries/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.17.1-37.1.0/forge-1.17.1-37.1.0-universal.jar`.

Second, trying to run it from there doesn't work:

```
[opc@better-minecraft1 ~]$ java -Xmx5120M -Xms2048M -jar ~/libraries/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.17.1-37.1.0/forge-1.17.1-37.1.0-universal.jar nogui
no main manifest attribute, in /home/opc/libraries/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.17.1-37.1.0/forge-1.17.1-37.1.0-universal.jar
```

Any ideas?  This is a headless linux server, so no gui tools.

The directory where all this was done now looks like this:

```
-rw-rw-r--.  1 opc opc        2 Dec  2 11:48 banned-ips.json
-rw-rw-r--.  1 opc opc        2 Dec  2 11:48 banned-players.json
-rw-rw-r--.  1 opc opc      180 Dec  2 11:38 eula.txt
-rw-rw-r--.  1 opc opc  2067991 Dec  2 11:42 forge-1.17.1-37.1.0-installer.jar.log
drwxrwxr-x. 12 opc opc     4096 Dec  2 11:41 libraries
drwxrwxr-x.  2 opc opc       78 Dec  2 11:48 logs
-rw-rw-r--.  1 opc opc        2 Dec  2 11:48 ops.json
-rw-rw-r--.  1 opc opc      362 Dec  2 11:41 run.bat
-rwxrw-r--.  1 opc opc      365 Dec  2 11:41 run.sh
-rw-rw-r--.  1 opc opc 43621201 Jun  8 11:03 server.jar
-rw-rw-r--.  1 opc opc     1037 Dec  2 11:48 server.properties
-rw-rw-r--.  1 opc opc        2 Dec  2 11:48 usercache.json
-rw-rw-r--.  1 opc opc      339 Dec  2 11:41 user_jvm_args.txt
-rw-rw-r--.  1 opc opc        2 Dec  2 11:38 whitelist.json
drwxrwxr-x. 10 opc opc     4096 Dec  2 14:03 world
```

Comment: Are you running this from your house Wi-Fi or did you rent out a server?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/how-to-set-up-and-run-a-really-powerful-free-minecraft-server-in-the-cloud

Comment: That's odd. Try the traditional "follow the tutorial again" and if that doesn't work lmk.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting confused with Paper.  You don't need to install vanilla Minecraft first, and you have it seems that Forge will only work if you install it in an empty directory.  Trying to install it on top of vanilla won't work.